# Why is CL = 1 - alpha

Tags: confidence-interval

The confidence level (CL) represents the proportion of confidence intervals that will contain the population parameter. The following formula was given to me as a way to determine the CL: $$ CL = 1- \alpha$$
where $\alpha$ is the two tailed equivalent.

My question is, why is this relation true? I don't see an immediate connection between alpha, which is a probability or area in the normal curve and the confidence level. I've heard it means that the confidence interval simply covers 95% of all data points in the normal curve but that doesn't sound right (and the normal curve of what are we even referring to?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by $\alpha$ being the "two-tailed equivalent". Confidence Level (CL) and $\alpha$, however, usually arise out of the context of hypothesis testing and frequentist inference. In hypothesis testing, we set a fixed null hypothesis, say $\mu=0$, and we want to see if there is evidence against this null. $\alpha$ usually represents the "Type 1 error", and is set *a priori* by the experimenter. It represents the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis given that it's true.

Now, the construction of confidence level was introduced as a way to refine this kind of "either/or" inference -- either reject or accept. So, in a way it represents the inverse of hypothesis testing. It asks, what value of $\mu$ can I set such that it will be rejected at $\alpha$ level? The region within which the hypothesis is not rejected is then the confidence interval. Now, note that
$$
\text{True $\mu$ outside region} \iff \text{True hypothesis rejected}
$$
Thus setting $P(\text{True hypothesis rejected})=\alpha$ implies $P(\text{True $\mu$ outside region}) = \alpha$. Thus $P(\text{True $\mu$ inside region})= 1-\alpha$. Hence, the confidence interval procedure would cover the true value $1-\alpha$ proportion of the time, and we therefore say the confidence level (CL) of the confidence interval is $1-\alpha$.